# How do I get ToolStripMenuItem Shortcut Key to work when WinForms control is hosted in VB6 Form

Tags: winforms, vb6, interop, keyboard-shortcuts

We have a scenario where we are exposing a set of WinForms `UserControls` via COM to a Legacy VB6 application. We have 3 different controls which have a `MenuStrip` on it that has the <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> shortcut key mapped to a menu item which invokes a control specific find items dialog when the shortcut is entered. When we try testing this code in our WinForms shell the appropriate dialog (the one hosted in the active `MdiChild`) pops up when all 3 controls exist, but in the VB6 host the wrong dialog usually appears (it seems to always be the dialog for the first control which was created).

I'm fairly certain this has something to do with message pumps and all, but I can't seem to figure out how to ensure that the proper `ToolStripMenuItem` is getting invoked when we enter the shortcut key.

I know the option of using a global/singleton `ShortcutKey` manager/service that overrides `ProcessCmdKey` is a possibility, but that would be the last resort we want to fall back on. I just get a feeling that a message pump needs to be started.

Answer (score 0):

This may be inappropriate to your needs.  And it might only apply to VB6 specifically.  But have you considered having VB6 use the standard menus, and just have it hold onto the keyboard shortcuts, and trigger things appropriately?  You could then simply hide the individual menus (but they should still fire their events).